# Couchbase Lite iOS and Server with SSL - Handshake failed: 400 Bad Request

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite

When Couchbase Lite iOS tries to start replications with a Couchbase server configured with SSL, you get an HTTP 400 Bad Request error: Handshake Failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future Googlers: I answer my own question in an attempt to save you of the headache that I endured. If you're using nginx, the problem is with the configuration file. You need to [add web socket support](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/sync-gateway/nginx/configuring-nginx-for-sync-gateway/index.html#websockets-support) to your configuration file. Restart nginx and relax, while Couchbase Lite iOS happily syncs with your server.